# How to check an object for null values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using an object type variable to store a query result for binding to a drop down list. I do not want further processing on an object if it is `null`.

My code is :

```
object course;
if (GetWebsiteCurrentMode().ToLower() == "demo")
{
    course = from t in context.CourseTestDetails
            join c in context.Courses
            on t.CourseID equals c.ID                                  
            where t.UserID == UserID && c.IsDeleted == true
            select new
            {
                c.ID,
                c.CourseName
            };

}
else
{
    course = from t in context.CourseTestDetails
            join c in context.Courses
            on t.CourseID equals c.ID                                  
            where t.UserID == UserID  c.IsDeleted == false
            select new
            {
                c.ID,
                c.CourseName
            }
}
if(course !=null )
{
    ddlCourseName.DataSource = course;
    ddlCourseName.DataBind();

    ddlCourseName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Course Name", "0"));
    ddlCourseName.SelectedValue = "0";
}
else
{
    //do something different
}
```

How can I check object type variable for null/empty?

Comment: I guess it would return a Empty enumerable and not null, so maybe you could check via [`.Any()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191919/what-does-linq-return-when-the-results-are-empty)

Comment: @V4Vendetta how to check for Empty enumerable ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417902/checking-if-object-is-null-in-c-sharp

Comment: @pwn you don't need the if statement as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object `course` would never be null, it may or may not contain record. Since you are getting the results back in `object`, you should cast it to IEnumerable`and use`Any` to see if it contains record. You can try:

```
if ((course as IEnumerable<object>).Any())
{
    //records found
}
{
    //no record found
}
```

Comment: @Serge, yes. It may be better to cast it to a separate variable and check if its not null *(to see if the casting succeeded)* , but the whole point is to cast it to `IEnumerable<T>` and then use `Any`

Comment: Is using Any more relevant than using Count()?

Comment: @Habib was just wondering about the cast to `IEnumerable<object>`, don't think object would be right candidate but then maybe i am wrong please do let me know if i am missing something

Comment: @Serge, yes see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305092/which-method-performs-better-any-vs-count-0

Comment: @V4Vendetta, the only reason I used casting to object is that the OP is projecting to anonymous type,

Answer (score 2):

```
if (course != null && (course as IEnumerable<object>).Any())
{
}
```

Optional: Additionally you should also check that object is implements IList interface

```
if (course  is IList)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The queries are not null but empty. But since you're using an object you cannot use `Enumerable.Empty`. You can use following trick from [E. Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751779/284240) to get one inferred-typed variable for multiple `IEnumerable<anynymous type>`:

Use this method to create a typed variable from an anonymous type:

```
static IEnumerable<T> SequenceByExample<T>(T t){ return null; }
```

Now this works:

```
var course = SequenceByExample(new { ID = 0, CourseName = "" } );
if (GetWebsiteCurrentMode().ToLower() == "demo")
{
    course = from t in context.CourseTestDetails
            join c in context.Courses
            on t.CourseID equals c.ID                                  
            where t.UserID == UserID && c.IsDeleted == true
            select new
            {
                c.ID,
                c.CourseName
            };
}
else
{
    course = from t in context.CourseTestDetails
    // ...
}
if(course.Any())
{
   // ...
}
else
{
    //do something different
}
```

[Declaring an implicitly typed variable inside conditional scope and using it outside](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8751779/284240)

Here's a simple example to demonstrate that it works: http://ideone.com/lDNl4d

Answer (score 0):

```
var course = from t in context.CourseTestDetails
                 join c in context.Courses
                 on t.CourseID equals c.ID                                  
                 where t.UserID == UserID && c.IsDeleted == (GetWebsiteCurrentMode().ToLower() == "demo")
                 select new
                 {
                     c.ID,
                     c.CourseName
                  };

if (course.Any()) ...
```